# Monitor a process without init?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, kodi

I have a bash script that runs a process -

```
it runs from an xsession /usr/share/xsessions/$user.desktop
```

I want to monitor the status of that process using monit.

Is it possible to create a pid and monitor that pid

If it finds the process has frozen or is unrespoinsive then run my script again to start the process again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor anything you want using `monit` - it's very flexible.  Depending upon what and how you want to monitor it, you'll have to dig into how the configuration works.

You first have to define what it means for your process to be "unresponsive."

[The "SERVICE TESTS" section of Monit  `man` page](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#service_tests) lists all the things that Monit can do to determine if something is running or not.

If you are particularly brave you could replace `init` with `monit` - but you probably have a lot of work ahead of you and the payoff is likely not going to be worth it.

You may also want to look into `upstart` as it's a "drop-in" (from what I hear) replacement for `init` that's designed to do things like this (but I don't know very much about it)

Comment: Thats great but - how would I monitor a process that wasnt started using init? would upstart subsitute that?

Comment: Ok I think I can alter my script to make a pid file then have one script to kill the program and delete the pid - this will form the basis for the monit service

Comment: You don't run `upstart` and `init` at once, I believe.  `upstart` is an `init` replacement with enhancements.